# Create Static Array from dynamic array with Generics

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, dynamic, static

I want to create a static array from a dynamic array of whatever generic type the dynamic array was. I saw List#toArray() which returns Object[] and it doesn't use generics. Is it just safe to cast it to T[] or does the entire array have to be instantiated from the type of class using it?

I went on to try and create my own method in case java didn't provide one but, I got stuck with a compile errors

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(List<T> list)
{
    T[] li = (T[]) Array.newInstance(T.class, list.size());
    int index = 0;
    for(T obj : list)
    {
        li[index++] = obj;
    }
    return li;
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid mixing Arrays and generics. Arrays are covariant and retained, while Generics are invariant and erased. This is a recipe for trouble. [Even `ArrayList` uses an `Object[]` as its backing structure](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) and only casts when elements are returned. --- Due to the erased nature of Generics, their type information is only available at compile-time, which is the reason why you cannot access `T.class` at runtime.

Comment: also note that above code using `newInstance()` is not better than `toArray()` - both need casting

Comment: If it were possible to do this, don't you think it would have been included in the collections API?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need that method. You can use:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("ff");
list.add("bb");
String[] array = list.toArray (new String[list.size ()]);
```

In order for your method to work, you have to pass the `Class` of the generic type parameter:

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz)
{
    T[] li = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size());
    int index = 0;
    for(T obj : list)
    {
        li[index++] = obj;
    }
    return li;
}
```

Then you can call the method with:

```
String[] array = toArray(list, String.class);
```

Comment: is it just safe to just cast to T[] using ArrayList#toArray()? Will it accept other objects that are not it's casted type?

Comment: @nullsector76 no. You'll get a ClassCastException, since `ArrayList#toArray()` returns an `Object[]`, which can't be cast to `T[]`. (unless T is also Object)

Answer (score 1):

The method proposed by Eran doesn't work if you have a generic element type, because you can't get a `Class<List<T>>`, say.

Instead, pass an `IntFunction<T[]>`:

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(List<? extends T> list, IntFunction<T[]> arraySupplier)
{
    T[] li = arraySupplier.get(list.size());
    int index = 0;
    for(T obj : list)
    {
        li[index++] = obj;
    }
    return li;
}
```

Or, easier, use streams:

```
return list.stream().toArray(arraySupplier);
```

Then call like:

```
String[] array = toArray(list, String[]::new);

List<List<String>> listOfLists = ...
List<?>[] arrayOfLists = toArray(listOfLists, List<?>::new);
```

Notice that whilst this does support generic array elements, you can only create arrays with a reified element type, so your array type has to be `List<?>[]`; it still can't be `List<String>[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If your business requirement/Use Case requires an array to be no longer dynamic then you should first create a static array of size equal to your size of dynamic array.

```
   ArrayList<Integer> al = [............] // assuming that ArrayList named al is having some data
   int[] arr = new int[al.size()];

   // from here you can use a for loop and initialize your static array
   for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
       arr[i] = (int) al.get(i); // Unboxing will also be done but still you can type cast to be on safe side
   }
   // Now you can de-reference the ArrayList object and call garbage collection which will wipe it out of the Heap Memory of your JVM.
   al = null; // de-referencing the object by making the reference variable null
   System.gc(); // GC happens periodically but to boost performance you can explicitly call it right away.
```

You can create a method accepting the list of objects and can handle all sorts of arrays using `instanceof` operator.

Comment: but `new` will not work with generic type `T` (main point of question - it is no problem to create an array at runtime if the type i known at compile time)